# sales_flat_quote_* vs enterprise_customer_sales_flat_customer_quote_*

Tags: database, sales, quote, ee-1.12

I'm looking to remove old quotes from the database via a Magento shell script, and I see `enterprise_customer_sales_flat_quote` and `enterprise_customer_sales_flat_quote_address` whose purpose is unclear to me. These are don't have any key constraint on them to the native Mage tables.

In the `Enterprise_Customer` module, under which the models for these tables are, there is not much responsible code. What are these for, and are they safe to remove along with the "associated" `sales_flat_quote/_address` records? ("associated" because there is no formal constraint but they seem to have the same `entity_id`s.

Answer (score 1):

These tables are mainly used when events are called, and there are a lot of them, all found in app/code/core/Enterprise/Customer/etc/config.xml:

```
<sales_quote_load_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesQuoteAfterLoad</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_load_after>
<sales_quote_address_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesQuoteAddressCollectionAfterLoad</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_address_collection_load_after>
<sales_quote_save_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesQuoteAfterSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_save_after>
<sales_quote_address_save_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesQuoteAddressAfterSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_address_save_after>
<sales_order_load_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderAfterLoad</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_load_after>
<sales_order_address_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderAddressCollectionAfterLoad</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_address_collection_load_after>
<sales_order_save_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderAfterSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_save_after>
<sales_order_address_save_after>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderAddressAfterSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</sales_order_address_save_after>
<enterprise_customer_attribute_before_save>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>enterpriseCustomerAttributeBeforeSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</enterprise_customer_attribute_before_save>
<enterprise_customer_attribute_save>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>enterpriseCustomerAttributeSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</enterprise_customer_attribute_save>
<enterprise_customer_attribute_delete>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>enterpriseCustomerAttributeDelete</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</enterprise_customer_attribute_delete>
<enterprise_customer_address_attribute_save>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>enterpriseCustomerAddressAttributeSave</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</enterprise_customer_address_attribute_save>
<enterprise_customer_address_attribute_delete>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>enterpriseCustomerAddressAttributeDelete</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</enterprise_customer_address_attribute_delete>
<core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_to_order>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetSalesConvertQuoteToOrder</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_to_order>
<core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_address_to_order_address>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetSalesConvertQuoteAddressToOrderAddress</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_address_to_order_address>
<core_copy_fieldset_sales_copy_order_to_edit>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetSalesCopyOrderToEdit</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_sales_copy_order_to_edit>
<core_copy_fieldset_sales_copy_order_billing_address_to_order>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetSalesCopyOrderBillingAddressToOrder</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_sales_copy_order_billing_address_to_order>
<core_copy_fieldset_sales_copy_order_shipping_address_to_order>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetSalesCopyOrderShippingAddressToOrder</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_sales_copy_order_shipping_address_to_order>
<core_copy_fieldset_customer_account_to_quote>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetCustomerAccountToQuote</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_customer_account_to_quote>
<core_copy_fieldset_customer_address_to_quote_address>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetCustomerAddressToQuoteAddress</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_customer_address_to_quote_address>
<core_copy_fieldset_checkout_onepage_quote_to_customer>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetCheckoutOnepageQuoteToCustomer</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_checkout_onepage_quote_to_customer>
<core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_address_to_customer_address>
    <observers>
        <enterprise_customer>
            <class>enterprise_customer/observer</class>
            <method>coreCopyFieldsetQuoteAddressToCustomerAddress</method>
        </enterprise_customer>
    </observers>
</core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_quote_address_to_customer_address>
```

It appears that what magento have done here is to latch onto the events rather than rewrite the community classes, which I think it a good solution from them.

If you look closely into one of these observers, we will take salesQuoteAfterLoad, it takes the quote from the observer and loads the enterprise version of it. It then calls attachAttributeData which simply adds all the data from the original quote into that enterprise quote.

```
public function salesQuoteAfterLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    if ($quote instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Abstract) {
        Mage::getModel('enterprise_customer/sales_quote')
            ->load($quote->getId())
            ->attachAttributeData($quote);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I would suggest looking at this observer you are fairly safe. If you are clearing the community tables then you can also clear the enterprise tables. But obviously backup your data first :)